# How to get a CSS3 animation to maintain its location after the animation has completed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I animate the labels on my form so that they move up and reduce in size when the input field has focus.

I use the forwards fill-mode which is supposed to maintain the final keyframe state.

However, this does not seem to be the case.  The labels jump down after the input field loses focus. How can I make sure the that labels will stay at the position they are in at the end of the animation even after the field loses focus?

```css
.bottomBox {
  background: white;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 640px;
  height: 595px;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}
.bottomBox h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.freeQuoteForm {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 530px;
  height: 430px;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
  text-align: left;
}
.formFields {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
  position: relative;
}
input,
textarea {
  font-family: "Sinkin Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  border: none;
}
.input {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}
.formLabel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-size: 70%;
  line-height: 8em;
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 3px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
  transform-origin: center left;
}
#lastName {
  border-left: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}
#lastName + .formLabel {
  left: 52%;
}
#lastName,
#firstName,
#email {
  padding-left: 12px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#email {
  width: 100%;
}
.input:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-animation: fadeColorBlue 2s 0s 1 ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: fadeColorBlue 2s 0s 1 ease-in-out forwards;
}
input:focus + .formLabel {
  -webkit-animation: colorScaleMove 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: colorScaleMove 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.input:valid {
  -webkit-animation: fadeColorWhite 4s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeColorWhite 4s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeColorBlue {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #e6f9ff;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeColorBlue {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #e6f9ff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeColorWhite {
  0% {
    background-color: #e6f9ff;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeColorWhite {
  0% {
    background-color: #e6f9ff;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes colorScaleMove {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.85) translateY(-34px);
    transform: scale(0.85) translateY(-34px);
    color: black;
  }
}
@keyframes colorScaleMove {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.85) translateY(-34px);
    transform: scale(0.85) translateY(-34px);
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomBox">
   <h3>Free Quote Form</h3>
   <form class="freeQuoteForm" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="formFields">
     <input type="text" id="firstName" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="firstName">First Name</label><input type="text" id="lastName" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="LastName">Last Name</label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="formFields">
     <input type="email" id="email" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="email">Email Address</label>
    </div>
   </form>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property-value pair `animation-fill-mode: forwards` is used to maintain the state as at the last keyframe of the animation ***only as long as the animation itself is applicable***. It would not maintain the state when the animation is no longer applicable (or has been ***removed***).

In your snippet, animation is applicable on the element only while the input has focus and so when it loses focus, the element (label) snaps back to its original position. If you want to keep the label as at the animation's end position then you should use JavaScript, listen for the [`animationend`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animationend) event, get the final `transform` value using `getComputedStyle` and set it back on to the element via inline styles like in the below snippet.

There is no pure CSS way to make the element retain its animation-end position even after animation has been removed from it.

**JS Code:**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.formLabel');
  for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener('animationend', function() {
      var currTransform = window.getComputedStyle(this).transform;
      this.style.transform = currTransform;
    });
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.formLabel');
  for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener('animationend', function() {
      var currTransform = window.getComputedStyle(this).transform;
      this.style.transform = currTransform;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.bottomBox {
  background: white;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 640px;
  height: 595px;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}
.bottomBox h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.freeQuoteForm {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 530px;
  height: 430px;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
  text-align: left;
}
.formFields {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
  position: relative;
}
input,
textarea {
  font-family: "Sinkin Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  border: none;
}
.input {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}
.formLabel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-size: 70%;
  line-height: 8em;
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 3px;
  transform-origin: center left;
}
#lastName {
  border-left: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}
#lastName + .formLabel {
  left: 52%;
}
#lastName,
#firstName,
#email {
  padding-left: 12px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#email {
  width: 100%;
}
.input:focus {
  outline: none;
  animation: fadeColorBlue 2s 0s 1 ease-in-out forwards;
}
input:focus + .formLabel {
  animation: colorScaleMove 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.input:valid {
  animation: fadeColorWhite 4s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeColorBlue {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #e6f9ff;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeColorWhite {
  0% {
    background-color: #e6f9ff;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
@keyframes colorScaleMove {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.85) translateY(-34px);
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomBox">
        <h3>Free Quote Form</h3>
        <form class="freeQuoteForm" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="formFields">
                <input type="text" id="firstName" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="firstName">First Name</label><input type="text" id="lastName" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="LastName">Last Name</label>

            </div>
            <div class="formFields">
                <input type="email" id="email" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="email">Email Address</label>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

(*Note that you may have to listen to browser prefixed versions of the `animationend` event also in case you need to support older browsers.*)

Comment: Thank you Harry for helping me to understand why the animation was not staying at the final position and also for your excellent suggestion on how to fix this.